# Having problems initialising a class into another class shows error code

Tags: python, kivy

Im having problems initialising the MyFirebase class into the Profile Window class, an error code is occurring in the App class constructor on the line `self.page = ProfileWindow(self.thefirebase)` and the error is  `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. if required to I can post the whole traceback. Here is the relevant part of my code

mainfile.py

```
from kivy.app import App
import requests
import json
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock




class MyFireBase():

    def __init__(self):
        self.localId = None
        self.sign_up_request = None


    def sign_up(self, email, password):

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            self.sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(self.sign_up_request.ok)
            print(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())


            if self.sign_up_request.ok == True:
                print(sign_up_data)
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']

                # Save refreshToken to a file
                with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write(refresh_token)


                app.local_id = self.localId
                app.id_token = idToken




                my_data =  '{"avatar": "profilepic.png", "jobs_done": "", "jobs_posted": ""}'
                post_request = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + self.localId + ".json?auth=" + idToken, data=my_data)
                print(post_request.ok)
                print(post_request.content.decode())

                app.root.current = "create"



            elif self.sign_up_request.ok == False:

                error_data = json.loads(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())
                error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
                app.root.ids.signup.ids.signup_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

    def send_user_details(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        my_data ={"first name": app.root.ids.create.ids.first_name.text, "last name": app.root.ids.create.ids.last_name.text,
                   "phone number": app.root.ids.create.ids.phone_number.text, "job1": app.root.ids.create.ids.job1.text, "job2": app.root.ids.create.ids.job2.text,
                   "job3": app.root.ids.create.ids.job3.text, "date of birth": app.root.ids.create.ids.date_of_birth.text, "state": app.root.ids.create.ids.state1.text}

        user_details = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + app.local_id + ".json?auth=" + app.id_token,  json.dumps(my_data))
        print(user_details.ok)
        print(user_details.content.decode())

        app.root.current = "main"



    def sign_in_existing_user(self, email, password):
        signin_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + self.wak
        signin_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
        signin_request = requests.post(signin_url, data=signin_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
        app = App.get_running_app()
        print(signin_request.ok)
        print(signin_request.content.decode())

        if signin_request.ok == True:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

            self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
            # Save refreshToken to a file
            with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(refresh_token)


            app.root.current = "main"


        elif signin_request.ok == False:
            error_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
            error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
            app.root.ids.login.ids.login_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")



thefirebase = MyFireBase()



class ProfileWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, thefirebase, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.thefirebase = thefirebase

    def print(self):
        print(self.thefirebase.localId)

class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    members_list = "members_list.txt"

    def build(self):
        self.thefirebase = MyFireBase()
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        self.page = ProfileWindow(self.thefirebase)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.manager)

        return sm
        # delay your call to sign_up() until the App is built




class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")


sm = WindowManager()


sm.current = "page"
```

kivy.kv

```
WindowManager:
    id: window manager
    ProfileWindow:
        id: page
        name: "page"
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/mainfile.py", line 144, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test5/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'thefirebase'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should not get that error on that line, since the `ProfileWindow` constructor takes any number of positional arguments (`*args`). Also the `Clock.schedule_once(self.call_signup)` will never be called since it appears after the `return`.

Comment: Even if you were going to use something like `if ... == True:`, in order to make things more explicit, it would be written `if ... is True:`. In general, it's best to just use `if ... :`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson any advice ? It happens every time I want to initialise to a screen class, is there another way to initialise a class in a screen class in kivy?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Please post the entire stack trace along with a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson Done, ill appreciate if you take your time to look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not coming from your App constructor, but from the `Builder.load_file()`. In your `kv` file you are building a `ProfileWindow`, but not providing the required positional argument of `firebase` to the constructor. I'm not sure there is a way to do that in `kv`. However, the `MyFireBase` instance can be built in the `kv` file and assigned to the `thefirebase` attribute of `ProfileWindow`

So, one solution is to remove the required positional argument from the `ProfileWindow` constructor, and pass the `firebase` using `kwargs`. Here is a modified version of your code that makes that change and builds `thefirebase` in the `kv` file (and make a few other changes):

```
from kivy.app import App
import requests
import json

from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyFireBase(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.localId = None
        self.sign_up_request = None

    def sign_up(self, email, password):

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            self.sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(self.sign_up_request.ok)
            print(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())


            if self.sign_up_request.ok == True:
                print(sign_up_data)
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']

                # Save refreshToken to a file
                with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write(refresh_token)

                app.local_id = self.localId
                app.id_token = idToken

                my_data =  '{"avatar": "profilepic.png", "jobs_done": "", "jobs_posted": ""}'
                post_request = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + self.localId + ".json?auth=" + idToken, data=my_data)
                print(post_request.ok)
                print(post_request.content.decode())

                app.root.current = "create"

            elif self.sign_up_request.ok == False:

                error_data = json.loads(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())
                error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
                app.root.ids.signup.ids.signup_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

    def send_user_details(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        my_data ={"first name": app.root.ids.create.ids.first_name.text, "last name": app.root.ids.create.ids.last_name.text,
                   "phone number": app.root.ids.create.ids.phone_number.text, "job1": app.root.ids.create.ids.job1.text, "job2": app.root.ids.create.ids.job2.text,
                   "job3": app.root.ids.create.ids.job3.text, "date of birth": app.root.ids.create.ids.date_of_birth.text, "state": app.root.ids.create.ids.state1.text}

        user_details = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + app.local_id + ".json?auth=" + app.id_token,  json.dumps(my_data))
        print(user_details.ok)
        print(user_details.content.decode())

        app.root.current = "main"

    def sign_in_existing_user(self, email, password):
        signin_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + self.wak
        signin_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
        signin_request = requests.post(signin_url, data=signin_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
        app = App.get_running_app()
        print(signin_request.ok)
        print(signin_request.content.decode())

        if signin_request.ok == True:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

            self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
            # Save refreshToken to a file
            with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(refresh_token)

            app.root.current = "main"

        elif signin_request.ok == False:
            error_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
            error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
            app.root.ids.login.ids.login_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

#thefirebase = MyFireBase()    # not needed
Factory.register('MyFireBase', cls=MyFireBase)   # register MyFireBase so that it is available in kv

class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    thefirebase = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.thefirebase = kwargs.pop('firebase', None)   # use kwargs to pass the firebase to eliminate the required positional arg
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #self.thefirebase = thefirebase   # not needed

    def print(self):
        print(self.thefirebase.localId)


class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    members_list = "members_list.txt"

    def build(self):
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        return sm


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")

#sm = WindowManager()    # not needed, sm is built by the `kv` file


# sm.current = "page"    # not needed, it is the default

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kivy.kv:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

WindowManager:
    id: window manager
    ProfileWindow:
        id: page
        name: "page"
        thefirebase: Factory.MyFireBase()   # this builds thefirebase
        Button:
            text: 'ProfileWindow'   # just so the ProfileWindow has something to display
            on_release: page.print()
```

Comment: The localId still returns as None bro :(

Comment: I think im meant to pass in the initialised firebase `self.thefirebase` into the factory but im unfamiliar with the factory documentation

Comment: The `localid` is returned as None becaue that is what it is set to in the `MyFireBase.__init__()` method.

Comment: do you know how to get the firebase value, that’s what I’m striving for ?

Comment: I assume you want to call some method that changes `localid`. You can do that in many ways. One approach, that has been previously discussed in one of your posts, is to call a method using `Clock.schedule_once()`.